# CPU and Thermal Types

Tags: cpu, motherboard, xeon, thermal-paste

I just noticed there were several types of pastes. Are some better then others? Such as when mounting a XEON chip is it better to use another paste over something basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any thermal paste made specifically for modern CPUs will work just fine. The differences between pastes are fairly minor and fall into a few categories:

1. Performance: A high-performance paste will keep your CPU a few degrees cooler.
2. Ease of application: Some pastes are conductive and require expertise to safely install. Some are basically foolproof.
3. Viscosity: Some pastes are thick and some are thin.

Just be sure both surfaces are as clean as possible before applying paste, apply the correct amount of paste, don't "twist" or slide excessively as you mate the CPU to the heat sink, and ensure the CPU and heat sink meet evenly with adequate pressure. If you don't get these things right, no paste will work well.

Comment: I largely agree - when using a "standard install", any thermal paste should do - but I think the statement the differences are fairly minor deserves qualification - the differences can be substantial both in cost and performance, but these should only come in to play when overclocking or there are specialist requirements, and often the application of the paste will make a bigger difference then the type of paste.